# drawing custom lines on highchart graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have recently been working with the highchart api to plot some data on a website, and I have need to be able to add a custom vertical "line" to symbolise something happening for example a press release.

I have thought about adding a column element to the chart as a seperate series but this is less than ideal.

if anyone has any ideas that would be awesome

thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Can you use the the `renderer` to draw the line?

Here is the [API doc for renderer](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer). Look at the `path` function.

Also check the *Try it* for jsfiddle for `path` function.

Comment: hi i had a similar query. problem with this is that if zoom into or out of the chart, the drawn svg lines do not rescale accordingly. similarly, the drawn lines are not exported. is there an alternate option which would take care of this, or should i go for handling these events manually?

Comment: @AtharvaJohri any progress in that matter?

Comment: hey.. i wrote my own javascript to handle rescaling, since I could not find anything in the API. Same for exporting.

Answer (score 6):

You can also check the `addPlotLine` or `addPlotBand` methods (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.addPlotLine and http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.addPlotBand).

It may be easier and quicker to use than drawing a SVG path, unless your line isn't straight.

Comment: This is a great answer and solved my problem, although unfortunately links are not working... somebody should tell the Highcharts team that  having urls with parenthesis is not such a hot idea.